# Outlook Add-in Property error

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to get the **SMTP Address** for an email and I have written a code to avoid getting the x.500 address. I get the SMTP address by accessing `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)` where `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"`;

However, this works on some laptops while some give an error saying

> "The property http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E is unknown or cannot be found."

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the **SMTP address**, you can create an [`Outlook.Recipient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867569.aspx) from the X.500 and resolve the [`Recipient.AddressEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863677.aspx) to an [`Outlook.ExchangeUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866281.aspx).

```
string address = string.Empty;
Outlook.Recipient recipient = mailItem.Application.Session.CreateRecipient(mailItem.SenderEmailAddress);
if (recipient != null && recipient.Resolve() && recipient.AddressEntry != null) 
{
    Outlook.ExchangeUser exUser = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
    if (exUser != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress))
      address = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
}
```

The error you are receiving with `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` indicates that the MIME property isn't present in the mail message properties and you need an alternate means to determine the senders SMTP address. You cannot assume a MIME property will always be present.

Comment: Thanks SilverNinja, what property should I access to get the email address for each of the other scenarios in the if statements.

Comment: I used the above code and it works on some outlook accounts but not on others. For the accounts it does not work, the recipient.resolve() comes as false. Not sure why. I checked the email address and it shows in x.500 format and I followed the code above to convert it to primarysmtpaddress but it fails at recipient.resolve().

Comment: Does **Check Names** work for the username? [`Recipient.Resolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librarY/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipient.resolve) just resolves the recipient against the users address book. If it cannot be resolved, an `AddressEntry` will not be found. As a fallback, you can check if the property [`PidLidInternetAccountName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202850%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) exists.

Comment: When you say as a fallback, should I check PidLidInternetAccountName property in the else statement for the outer if in the code above? If that's true, how should I proceed with getting the primarysmtpaddress? The same way as explained above?

Comment: I get it now when you say fallback. So if PidLidInternetAccountName specifies the user-visible email account name through which the email is sent, why dont we just use this property rather than going through the code that you mentioned above?